# normalize my table according to my ranges

Tags: r, normalize

I want to normalize all my table (not by column or row) according to the max and min of all table.

for ex:

[image]

in these whole table :
max : 9
min:  0

so I want to normalize all these numbers between 0 and 9 to between 0 and 1!

Any helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard formula for such normalisation is

```
(xi - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))
```

So for this data we can do

```
vals <- unlist(df)
max_val <- max(vals)
min_val <- min(vals)
df[] <- (vals - min_val)/(max_val - min_val)

df
#  column1 column2 column3
#1  0.1111  0.3333  1.0000
#2  0.2222  0.4444  0.6667
#3  0.3333  0.6667  0.3333
#4  0.4444  0.3333  0.1111
#5  0.5556  0.0000  0.7778
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(column1 = 1:5, column2 = c(3, 4, 6, 3, 0), 
                 column3 = c(9, 6, 3, 1, 7))
```

Comment: dear @ronak, if we want to change the range (0-1) to for ex. 0-2 what can we do in this function? thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't just multiplying by 2 to the above give you the answer?

Comment: if  I want to normalize only rows?

Comment: Put the above code in a function and use `apply` with margin 1 to apply the function.